# Method uploadStoredFiles does not exist on jQuery.fineUploader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fine-uploader

I'm having trouble uploading my fine-uploader's file manually.
I have a basic form which contains my own angularJS directive :

```html
<div id="myUploader" aw-uploader
     uploader-instance="vm.uploaderInstance" endpoint="/api/addpictures"
     >
</div>
```

This Angular directive instanciate the FineUploader like this :

```js
  function awUploader() {
        var directive = {
            replace: true,
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: '/App/Common/Layout/awUploader.directive.html',
            scope: {
                endpoint: '@'               
            }
        };

        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).fineUploader({
                template: 'qq-template-gallery',
                request:
                    endpoint: scope.endpoint
                },
                thumbnails: {

            });
            scope.uploaderInstance = $(element);                
        }
```

All of that seems to work so far. But now, I need to submit the files manually after the rest of the data contained by my form.
As my form is controlled by a JS script, I'd like to trigger the file upload manually. Like this :

```
uploaderInstance.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
```

I already checked that "uploaderInstance" variable contains the DOM element I instanciated FU on (here, it's the #myUploader div element. Right?). And it's fine.

But when I try to execute the instruction, an error is thrown w/ the famous "Method uploadStoredFiles does not exist on jQuery.fineUploader".

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: could you provide the full code, because now it's not clear where do you have Angular

Comment: Is it more clear after this edit?

Comment: and you don't need to do "$(element)" because element is instance of jQuery, so element.fineUploader(...) should work

Comment: You were right STEVER, element.fineUploader works well.
Anyway, it doesn't solve my problem. I still can't have access to the fine-uploader instance. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

The error message you have listed suggests that your Fine-Uploader-bound element is not actually bound to a Fine Uploader instance when you are calling `uploaderInstance.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles')`. There is at least one major syntax error in your code (missing an ending brace for the `thumbnails` option). So you'll want to look a bit closer at your code to figure out:

1. If Fine Uploader is even being properly initialized.
2. If the element is being manipulated in some way by your code such that the initialized Fine Uploader instance is being disassociated from the element.

Comment: Hey Ray, thanks for your reply.
About the syntax error, it's because I edited the code inside SO editor. It works well in my "real file" though.
About your suggestions : 
1. FU is properly initialized, I can check that because I can use it normal way (DnD files in the canvas, etc).
2. As you said, it seems like my element is being dissociated from the FU instance. And I don't know why.
If I add the uploaderInstance.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles'); right after the scope.uploaderInstance = $(element);   (in the Angular directive), it works well.
Still don't get the problem here..

Comment: What does actually represent the fineUploader instance? Is it only the DOM element that "carries" it?
Does it worth it to try FU without jQuery?